# Spring changes finding beans from version 4.3 to 5

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a large spring applications using annotations that works fine in spring 4.3.13, and am looking to update to spring 5. I am getting all kinds of failures wiring beans, which look like the typical:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pcoDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.acme.dao.impl.contracts.PotentialChangeOrderDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

turning on spring debug logging, only nets this additional line

```
Failed to meta-introspect annotation interface org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It's not like all @Autowired fields fail, just this one (so far).  The bean is specified by an interface, and the implementation is in a sub package of the interface, but again this worked before. The interface's package is specified directly in the 
context:component-scan
        base-package="com.acme.package.of.interface"

Again this works fine in 4.3.13, and the *only* change is spring being upgraded to 5.0.5-RELEASE.

Are they any known changes to how spring finds beans? or any documentation about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems a bug of Spring 5.0.5, and has been fixed in 5.0.6, see this [Null check needed in AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16708)

Comment: thanks, looks likely. now just have to wait for 5.0.6, i guess

Comment: Y not. i got lot of time saving from your answer

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the implementations of respect interface, If it is not there provide implementation.
If implementation is there please check whether they have class level annotation as @Component or any specific annotations.
For info related auto wiring read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_beans_autowiring.htm).